# android how update drawer menu after oncreate method

Tags: android, oncreate, drawer

How Can I change some options on my Drawer Menu after execute onCreate method?

I tap on "Configuration" option of my App, change some parameters and save to DB, when return to Main Intent and call the menu, I want to see "new" options because I changed the Configuration ..... It's only Works when exit of the App and enter again.

The Configuration intent extends PreferenceActivity

Regards

Comment: please implements DrawerListener

Comment: Krunal: In DrawerLister method I have to write again all menu?

Comment: Ok .... will be in onDrawerOpened method ... always I have to "reloaded" when open the menu

Comment: Ya perfect. You have to reload in this method.

Comment: I have gotten this message ..... Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.

Comment: I have gotten this message: Cannot add header view to list setAdapter has already been called

Comment: This indicated that you have already add headerview just update the value.

Comment: Doesen't Works..View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_drawer, null);
 TextView et = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.nom_sede);
 //Get the new values for the header
 String nomSucursal = getNomSede();
 et.setText(nomSucursal);
 mDrawerList.refreshDrawableState();

Comment: First define headerview as class variable. Then in oncreate mehod initialize this variable. And when ondraweropen method call that time just change the value. Mean you can change value in ondraweropen method. Not add more layout in this method.

Comment: Please share your updated code, so i will figure out issues.

Comment: Ya perfect! Thank you Krunal